Convert partial eta squared to Cohen’s d
I need to convert partial eta squared ("pes") to Cohen’s d.
Hence, I'd like to verify the formula I've used below, where "n.total" represents the total number of participants (both experimental and control).
The samples are independent.
cohen.d <- sqrt((n.total-1)/n.total*pes/(1-pes))


Your formula should probably be more like cohen.d <- sqrt(pes / (1 - pes)) * sqrt((n1 + n2) / (n1 * n2))

That should be fine, but I prefer to be a little more explicit with parentheses, and you will thank yourself later if you roll the code into a function that you can use over and over again if you need to, so I would do something like this:
pes_to_cohens_d = function(pes, n) sqrt( ((n-1)/n) * (pes/(1-pes)) )
pes_to_cohens_d(pes, n.total)

